# MySQL equivalent of PostgreSQL's dblink module?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, dblink

PostgreSQL's [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/dblink.html) module allows for SQL statements to be written that execute other SQL statements against a remote PostgreSQL database.

Is there an equivalent to PostgreSQL's dblink for MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly.

There is, however the `FEDERATED` storage engine (available since 5.0.3), which can be used in certain situations to emulate this behaviour. It is, (put very simply) a `VIEW` for a remote table.

There is an in-depth explanation, along with examples on [its MySQL manual page(s)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html).

Comment: Oh yea. I always forget that exists. Does anyone even use FEDERATED?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [MySQL Proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy).  This doesn't match the architecture of dblink, but you can probably solve a similar set of problems that you would use dblink to solve.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible with MySQL. The closest you can come is to use replication to replicate the tables you need from the "remote" database down to the slave you are querying on. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html) for more details.