# postgreSQL to MySQL converter

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a table in a postgreSQL database that I would like to convert into a MySQL table. What would be the easiest way to do this? Any tools to do this? Remember, I am not converting the whole database to MySQL... I am just taking a table from that postgreSQL and convert it to MySQL table

Comment: Related: PostgreSQL's dblink functionality & MySQL's - see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185742/mysql-equivalent-of-postgresqls-dblink-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgdump.html) to create a SQL dump from a single table and use this dump as input for [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html). Take a look at the option `--data-only` when you already have the tablestructure in your MySQL database and `--column-inserts` to create straight forward INSERT statements.

Answer (score 0):

An ETL tool like SSIS, Pentaho, Talend or several others will do the trick. Most support a wide variety of data sources and destinations.